# ImGui manager singleton

Tags: c++

For my game engine I am implementing ImGui for debugging purposes. In order to manage ImGui I have made a singleton to make sure only one ImGui context gets created. I am not entirely sure if this is a good implementation of a Singleton so I am looking for some feedback, also is using a Singleton here the right way or could I better use a full static class?

**ImGUIManager.h**

```
#ifndef CHEETAH_CORE_IMGUIMANAGER_H_
#define CHEETAH_CORE_IMGUIMANAGER_H_

#include "Core.h"
#include "../ImGUI/imgui.h"

#include <memory>

namespace cheetah
{
    class CH_API ImGUIManager
    {
    public:
        static void init();
        static void shutDown();
        static void begin();
        static void end();

        static inline ImFont* getTextFont() { return ImGUIManager::getInstance()->m_text; };
        static inline ImFont* getIconSmallFont() { return ImGUIManager::getInstance()->m_iconSmall; };
        static inline ImFont* getIconLargeFont() { return ImGUIManager::getInstance()->m_iconLarge; };

        virtual ~ImGUIManager() = default;

    protected:  
        ImGUIManager() = default;
        virtual void init_impl() = 0;
        virtual void shutDown_impl() = 0;
        virtual void begin_impl() = 0;
        virtual void end_impl() = 0;

    protected:
        ImFont* m_text = nullptr;
        ImFont* m_iconSmall = nullptr;
        ImFont* m_iconLarge = nullptr;

    private:
        static ImGUIManager* getInstance();
        static void create();

    private:
        static std::unique_ptr<ImGUIManager> m_instance;
    };
}

#endif // !CHEETAH_ENGINE_IMGUI_IMGUIMANAGER_H_
```

**ImGUIManager.cpp**

```
#include "ImGUiManager.h"
#include "Renderer/RenderAPI.h"
#include "Platform/OpenGL/OpenGLImGUIManager.h"

namespace cheetah
{
    std::unique_ptr<ImGUIManager> ImGUIManager::m_instance = nullptr;

    void ImGUIManager::init()
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        static bool initialized = false;
        ASSERT(!initialized, "ImGUI is already initialized");
#endif // DEBUG
        ImGUIManager::getInstance()->init_impl();
#ifdef DEBUG
        initialized = true;
#endif
    };

    void ImGUIManager::shutDown()
    {
        ImGUIManager::getInstance()->shutDown_impl();
    };

    void ImGUIManager::begin()
    {
        ImGUIManager::getInstance()->begin_impl();
    };

    void ImGUIManager::end()
    {
        ImGUIManager::getInstance()->end_impl();
    };

    ImGUIManager* ImGUIManager::getInstance()
    {
        if (!m_instance)
            ImGUIManager::create();

        return m_instance.get();
    }

    void ImGUIManager::create()
    {
        switch (RenderAPI::getAPI())
        {
        case RenderAPI::API::OpenGL:
            m_instance = std::make_unique<opengl::OpenGLImGUIManager>();
            break;
        default:
            m_instance = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not thread safe!

Looks like you can still create instances manually (though you would have to derive a class that can use the protected constructor) or copy the one created by `getInstance()`.

Why not use the classic Singleton pattern?

```
class ImGUIManager
{
     public:
         static ImGUIManager& getInstance()
         {
             static ImGUIManager instance;   // static member
                                             // Correctly constructed on first use.
                                             // Will be deleted on exit.
             return instance;
         }
         // PUT YOUR INTERFACE HERE

     private:
         ImGUIManager(){} // Make sure the constructor is private.
         // Delete the copy and move constructors.
         ImGUIManager(ImGUIManager const&)            = delete;
         ImGUIManager& operator=(ImGUIManager const&) = delete;
         ImGUIManager(ImGUIManager&&)                 = delete;
         ImGUIManager& operator=(ImGUIManager&&)      = delete;
};
```

Some References:

[C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/14065)

Comment: The protected constructor is there with a reason, because this class can have different implementations per example with OpenGL and Vulkan, these implementations are defined in a derived class. also could you explain what your example makes it thread safe? I have no experience with threading in c++ so I have some difficulty seeing how this would make it thread safe.

Comment: @RickNijhuis The construction of static storage duration objects is guaranteed by the standard to be thread safe.

Comment: If you want want to have more than one implementation (presumably only one is ever valid during runtime (otherwise how is it a singleton) then you need to combine this pattern with the factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not entirely sure if this is a good implementation of a Singleton so I am looking for some feedback, also is using a Singleton here the right way or could I better use a full static class?

I believe there's no added value to that setup and you'd be better off without it. This is just extra code and more complexity.

Supposedly you are trying to solve "to make sure only one ImGui context gets created", is that a real problem you have or an hypothetical problem?

My advice, don't create code that don't solve important problem. By doing so you are not spending time working on useful features and important problems. This is not an important problem. People on those communities will often tell you the opposite, ask them what software they are shipped.